# SQL Server : BCP export NULL results

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, export, bcp

I'm using this bcp cmd to export a long query result that generate an XML. 
So I've a @DTE VARIABLE set with @DTE = 'select.... where.... FOR XML PATH'
and a variable containing a dinamic file name.

```
SET @cmd = 'bcp "' + @DTE + '" queryout "' + @Filename + '"  -k -x -w';


EXEC master..XP_CMDSHELL @cmd;
```

The result of this export is this:

```
> output
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- usage: bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile  
> [-m maxerrors]            [-f formatfile]          [-e errfile]   [-F
> firstrow]             [-L lastrow]             [-b batchsize]   [-n
> native type]          [-c character type]      [-w wide character
> type]   [-N keep non-text native] [-V file format version] [-q quoted
> identifier]   [-C code page specifier]  [-t field terminator]    [-r
> row terminator]   [-i inputfile]            [-o outfile]            
> [-a packetsize]   [-S server name]          [-U username]           
> [-P password]   [-T trusted connection]   [-v version]             [-R
> regional enable]   [-k keep null values]     [-E keep identity values]
> [-h "load hints"]         [-x generate xml format file] 
NULL

(12 row(s) affected)
```

If I execute the query without bcp, I've correct results.
Why there's a NULL OUTPUT with bcp?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the query have to be on 1 single line. My query was on multiple lines.